# GNU make auto dependency generation

Tags: linux, sed, gnu-make

I am learning GNU make recently. The following is the example of auto-dependency generation from the GNU make manual. I know the general meaning the above script (it's basically replacing something with something else with the `sed` command). But I have two questions with respect to the details in the command. First, what does the `\1.o` mean in the command? Is it related to  position parameter? And second, why `$*` is put into a pair of `()` since `$*` itself already means the stem of the target filename? (I tried to without the parenthesis, it didn't work.)

```
%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                  \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
```

I tried the following, it didn't work.

```
%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                  \
    sed 's,$*\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
```

Can anyone explain the reasons behind? Thanks.

Comment: Those are both `sed` details and not makefile details. That's a `sed` command you are looking at.

Comment: $* is the automatic variable in makefile. @EtanReisner

Comment: Did you try `'s,$*\.o[ :]*,$*.o $@ : ,g'`?

Comment: \1 means: replace with the text matched inside the first (escaped) parenthesis pair.The escaped parenthesis are not matched by the engine.

Comment: I just tried it. This one works successfully. Can you explain why this work? @5gon12eder

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you make it a little bit more clear? @xvan

Comment: True, the `$*` is part of the makefile syntax. It gets expanded to the stem just as you said. That is then used as part of the `sed` command (which is where the `(` and `)` come in. As I said that's just a `sed` command at that point. Look at the output from `make -p` and at the output of running `make` (when it generates the `.d` files).

Comment: `echo filename1.c filename2.c  | sed 's/filename\([0-9]*\)\.c/output\1.o/g'`  => `output1.o output2.o`.

Answer (score 4):

The text is [interpreted multiple times](https://www.xkcd.com/1638/).

```
's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g'
```

In the first step, Make expands the `$` variables.  For example:

```
's,\(foo\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o foo.d : ,g'
```

Next, this string is passed to the Shell, which strips off the quotation.

```
s,\(foo\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o foo.d : ,g
```

Finally, it is interpreted by `sed`. In basic regular expressions as understood by `sed` by default, `\(…\)` simply matches `…` but *groups* the match. Then later, in the replacement, you can refer back to the text that was matched.  `\N` refers to the *N*-th group that was matched. So in this example, `\1` simply refers back to whatever `$*` matched – probably `foo`. (You might get into troubles if `$*` expands to something that has a special meaning inside a regular expression. Note that back references make regular expression non-regular, but that's probably irrelevant here.)

From my understanding, this is not a very robust way to write the replacement and there is really no need to use a back-reference here. The desired effect could have been achieved more robustly by a replacement like this.

```
's,[^:]*:,$*.o $@ :,g'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind and detailed reply. @5gon12eder

Comment: Your suggested replacement is a lot more permissive than the original. It will match *many* more things than the original will. Now, that may not matter in this case (because the input is constrained) but I'm not about that and even if that is the case it is still a difference that is worth noting.

Comment: @EtanReisner Absolutely, I'm not claiming that the suggested alternative is equivalent. What I do believe is that it might be more appropriate for the specific task at hand.